# Get some data but not all using regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have some data like this:

```
disconnected, received disassoc: sending station leaving (8)
disconnected, 4-way handshake timeout
disconnected, too weak signal, signal strength -91
disconnected, registered to other interface
```

I would like to get the reason without the number and parentheses.
So not to include any `(x)` nor `-xx` where x is number (at the end)

Output should be

```
received disassoc: sending station leaving
4-way handshake timeout
too weak signal, signal strength
registered to other interface
```

I think I need some lookahed but not sure.

This does not work:

```
disconnected, (?<reason>.*)( -\d+)?
```

reason will still include the `-91`

This gives only lines with -xx or (x), missing rest of the lines

```
disconnected, (?<reason>.+(?=-\d+|\(\d\)))
```

This gives all lines but will also include -xx and (x) in the reason

```
disconnected, (?<reason>.+(?=-\d+|\(\d\))?)
```

PS `-xx` and `(x)` are always at the end so can use anchor `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an alternation with an optional non capturing group to match both options at the end of the string.

The value is in the named capture group `reason`.

```
disconnected, (?<reason>.*?)(?:\(\d+\)| -\d+)?$
```

*In parts*

- `disconnected,`  Match disconnected, and a space
- `(?<reason>.*?)` Named capture group `reason`, match any char as least as possible
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\(\d+\)` Match 1+ digits between parenthesis
  - `|` Or
  - `-\d+` Match a space `-` and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close group and make optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmQbb7/1)